# Is there any way to get Visual Studio to reload all projects when the .proj files have changed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

If I do an svn update while I have Visual Studio open and a number of project files have changed (but not the solution file) I have to wait and click yes on the reload project dialog box every time.  Sometimes this can take a while depending on how many projects have changed and how slow my pc is being.

Is there a way to say 'reload all' after the first dialog pops up, like holding down shift to force no to all in the Windows Explorer dialog? (note: I already tried this, it doesn't work)

Comment: I got the same issue with TFS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a tool like [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com) to automate the process for you. It allows you to perform the update within Visual Studio, then automatically reloads the projects that have been modified.

Comment: All very well if you use subversion. Are you aware of a git/perforce equivalent?

Comment: GitExtensions integrates GIT with VS.  https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions  Perforce version here:  https://www.perforce.com/plugins-integrations/visual-studio-plugin

Answer (score 22):

if you install this plugin from the visual studio gallery:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf/

The button "Reload all" appears.

Regards,
Koen

Comment: It seems to overlap with a lot of what ReSharper already does for me. Can I install them together?

Answer (score 20):

Deleting my **solution_name.v11.suo** file (hidden file stored in same location as solution file) seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Same here! Good spot +1

Comment: Thank-you very much! On VS Community 2017 the file has been moved to folder/.vs/SolutionName/v15

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, VS doesn't come with a way to do this. A probable workaround is to touch the solution file before activation VS. It would then reload the whole solution.

There must, however, be ways to do this programmatically, since I remember CMake solutions asking me whether I wanted to reload the whole solution after individual projects were re-generated. CMake is Open Source, so if you're really desperate, you might want to look into it.

Answer (score 4):

I got my project to bind in my solution by closing the solution (File -> Close Solution) then reopening it.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is hosted on a TFS, then delete the solution file and get latest. VS will prompt you to Reload all projects. Press *Reload All*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit automation here, in case you have multiple solutions and [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) installed (also available for windows), `fd -IH suo -X rm` will delete all those `.suo` files pointed out by Luke.