# How to reload a property sheet in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, propertysheet

Is there a way to reload a property sheet that was edited outside of Visual Studio? Visual Studio doesn't detected automatically that the file was modified (like it does with project files). The only way I've found so far is to close and reopen the whole solution (but that's no good way).

Comment: Removing and adding it back would be another way.  You probably don't like that either.  I'd recommend my doctor's advice, if it hurts then don't do it.

Comment: This solution is even worse as it'll "remove" dependency information in other projects.

Comment: Hmm, no, not the project, just the property sheet.

Comment: Ah - ok. But that only works (easily) if it's not being use by multiple project, right?

Answer (score 5):

Only a partial solution perhaps for your (and my) needs, but I've found it helpful to `touch` the .sln file.  This causes Visual Studio to wig out and ask if you want to reload all the projects.  Select "Yes" and then you'll notice the properties have refreshed.  I make sure that my scripts which update property files also touch any related solution file(s).

Also see [Is there any way to get Visual Studio to reload all projects when the .proj files have changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376917/is-there-any-way-to-get-visual-studio-to-reload-all-projects-when-the-proj-file)

Comment: Do you mean editing (e.g. add a space) the sln with external text editor?

Comment: Yes, the Unix/Linux "touch" program simply updates the timestamp on the file without making other changes to the file so that Visual Studio will reload everything. Adding whitespace in the sln will do the same thing.  I use the "touch" for Windows that's included with git (also msys2).